# Eclipse font/language error

Tags: eclipse, utf-8, fonts

Source code like this and show result on browser same as code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEpN2.jpg)

I try with UTF-8 but it can't help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXGvt.jpg)

example : ��è��ҡ����������ҡѺ

�е�ͧ���¡���������ҡѺ

Can I solve this in Eclipse or I have to translate it (but I don't know what type of these fonts) ?

Comment: What is the expected content for those example?

Comment: Changing the text file encoding setting does not change the file, it is only for how a text file is displayed and how new characters are inserted. If UTF-8 is not used, the country-specific code page is often used. Therefore, it would be good to know what language setting the computer on which the text was written had. It could also be that the font used does not support the characters. This can be checked by copying the characters into a UTF-8 file.

Comment: I want to convert it to text @samabcde

Comment: I don't  know what is that message was, I think it's my local language. I try to convert it to text but I don't know how to do? Can I use this https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter to convert it? @howlger

Answer (score 0):

A JSP file, just like a XML file, declares within its own contents what encoding to use. You've set it to be read as UTF-8 even though the contents declare it to use TIS-620, most likely in the `pageEncoding` value of the page directive. Once the text is read by the browser or JSP editor, the font has to support the characters that are there or you will continue to get the incorrect appearance regardless. Not all fonts support all the valid characters.

Close the JSP editor, change the file property dialog back to using the default encoding for its contents, and then reopen the file and change the encoding in the `page` directive.

Comment: I use the default encoding the result is >>> https://imgur.com/qGDY2jb
I have to edit charset to UTF-8 right? >> https://imgur.com/msQqaMY

Comment: Do you? TIS-620 is a valid encoding.